# if array exists, then continue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that might be present in my .aspx page, if it is, I want to fire a javascript function.

I tried:

```
if(someArray)
       blah(someArray);
```

but I get an error when I havent' defined someArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be pre-defining the array as null and check to see if it resolves, rather than *sometimes* available.

```
Array someArray = null;

// this is where you'll populate or replace someArray
// if you don't, someArray simply remains empty

if (someArray)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't even bother to create an empty array. Null is perfectly fine:

var someArray = null;

// Initialize

if(someArray) alert(someArray);

Answer (score 8):

```
if(typeof someArray !== 'undefined') {
    blah(someArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [];
var b = new Array();
alert(typeof a === "object" && a instanceof Array);
alert(typeof b === "object" && b instanceof Array);
alert(typeof c === "object" && c instanceof Array);
```